# How can I change the if else statement in the function with Ternary operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, conditional-operator

How can I change the if else statement in the function with Ternary operator in JavaScript

```
private getProductName(productType: string): string {
    let productName = 'Product not found';

    if(this.deal.packages.find(p  => p.isSelected).dealProducts.find(dp => (dp.children.length > 0 && dp.children[0].product.productTypeCode == productType))){
      productName = this.deal.packages.find(p  => p.isSelected).dealProducts.find(dp => (dp.children.length > 0 && dp.children[0].product.productTypeCode == productType)).children[0].product.name;
    }
    else if(this.deal.packages.find(p  => p.isSelected).dealProducts.find(dp => (dp.children.length === 0 && dp.product.productTypeCode === productType))){
      productName = this.deal.packages.find(p  => p.isSelected).dealProducts.find(dp => (dp.children.length === 0 && dp.product.productTypeCode === productType)).product.name;
    }

    return productName;
}
```

Comment: weird looking JavaScript

Comment: Maybe the OP first wants to provide readability to the code by assigning some of the repeatedly accessed references to variables/constants. Then is also much easier to replace the *if-else* clauses by a ternary expression.

Comment: So the code is not readable, and you want to deteriorate the readability further? Did I get that right?

Comment: To improve your code I would suggest: It's more valuable to have readable code, than it is to have extreme compact code. Also break your long code lines. Create named variables instead of long if clauses or extract them to "isFooBar* methods. Extract methods from the code next to "productName =". Fix your method spelling at the top. After all that it should be easy to introduce the tenary operator. As a tip: Read Uncle Bobs book Clean Code.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, no, no, this was to the OP ;-)

Comment: @PeterSeliger your missionary cleancode behaviour does not belong to the question.

Comment: @nologin That is your opinion. Someone can write a book on a whiteboard, erase the entire thing and rewrite it to fix a single typo. Or someone can just optimize it from the start and not erase the entire whiteboard. The code above basically finds the object to say it exists. It then throws it away to find it again. That is not the best logic. Giving ideas on how to structure the code better is an answer. I am sorry you do not feel strongly about that. Some times a person asks for something, but in the end that something is not what the OP really needs.

Comment: @espascarello You do not have to read the code to translate an if/else-statement into ternary operators. (I did not! Because it is not readable!)
Thus this is not part of this question. Btw. I do clean code trainings in dev-teams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is very inefficient because you find the thing, and then you turn around and find the thing again. So you end up looping multiple times.

To make it more readable, I broke it up into parts. It also loops one time over the object to locate the items with children and the items without children. There is a ternary operator there to handle with and without.

The code then determines if it is the child or not and grabs the object.

```
// Grab the package
var selectedPackageProducts = this.deal.packages.find(p => p.isSelected).dealProducts;

// check to see if the children has the product type or if the parent does (if no children)
const selectedProduct = selectedPackageProducts.find(dp => 
    dp.children.length > 0 ? 
    dp.children[0].product.productTypeCode === productType :
    dp.product.productTypeCode === productType)

// If we have children use it, else reference the parent
const productObj = selectedProduct && selectedProduct.children.length ? 
    selectedProduct.children[0] :
    selectedProduct;

// get the product name 
const productName = productObj && productObj.product.name
```

Comment: You missed dp.children.length === 0 in the else part and please note I am getting product.name differently in both if statement and else statement.

Comment: @KarimAli um, if the children is > 0.... the children will be zero in the else part of the ternary

Comment: altered it slightly to reference the child

Answer (score 1):

I put myself under risk, entering what meanwhile seems to be a battleground of opinions, in order to prove two things.

1. Aiming for clean code and readability is not always just for the sake of being missionary or a *"I do know better than you"* attitude. It is mostly for one's own peace and health (and the one of the team) and especially for the one's that have to maintain such code soon after and even later.
2. By refactoring the OP's code towards readability one achieves three things:

- cutting back the repeated and unnecessary data access to the most necessary ones, and then exactly once.
- actually making it obvious/readable (thus easier to refactor) what kind of data one is dealing with.
- and finally fulfilling the OP's wish of a return-value based on (nested) ternary operators which was not such an easy task to achieve without cleaning up before.

---

```
private getProductName(productType: string): string {
  const defaultProductName = 'Product not found';

  const selectedPackageProductList = this.deal.packages
    .find(p => p.isSelected).dealProducts;

  const selectedProducts = selectedPackageProductList
    .find(dp => (dp.children.length > 0 && dp.children[0].product.productTypeCode === productType));

  const selectedProductItem = !selectedProducts && selectedPackageProductList
    .find(dp => (dp.children.length === 0 && dp.product.productTypeCode === productType));

  return selectedProducts
    ? selectedProducts.children[0].product.name
    : (selectedProductItem ? selectedProductItem.product.name : defaultProductName);
}
```

Comment: Only thing I would change with yours is skip the ternary, add if before the selectedProductItem.... why do the selectedProductItem loop if you already found something?

Comment: @epascarello ... With keeping the *ternaries* I want to satisfy the question's requirements and please the OP and *nologin*. Regarding the suggested improvements, `selectedProductItem` gets computed just in case `selectedProducts` does not exist (there is a guard for that). This is also the reason one can write the final return value as requested by the OP. At this point it is just about retrieving the *product name*.

Comment: As I made in a comment under the post, sometimes what the OP asks is not what they really need. ;) But with the edit, it does the same thing.

Comment: I have been using **O**riginal **P**oster for 12 years on here, I do not plan on changing.

Comment: Aiming for clean code is a good thing. But it does not answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of writing:
`IF condition THEN do_a ELSE do_b` you can use ternary operators the same way.

`(condition) ? do_a : do_b;`

Concrete for your example:

```
private getProductName(productType: string): string {
    return (this.deal.packages.find(p  => p.isSelected).dealProducts.find(dp => (dp.children.length > 0 && dp.children[0].product.productTypeCode == productType)))
 ? this.deal.packages.find(p  => p.isSelected).dealProducts.find(dp => (dp.children.length > 0 && dp.children[0].product.productTypeCode == productType)).children[0].product.name;
 : (this.deal.packages.find(p  => p.isSelected).dealProducts.find(dp => (dp.children.length === 0 && dp.product.productTypeCode === productType)))
 ? this.deal.packages.find(p  => p.isSelected).dealProducts.find(dp => (dp.children.length === 0 && dp.product.productTypeCode === productType)).product.name;
 : 'Product not found';
}
```

Btw. I recommend to extract methods for `do_a` or `do_b`.

Comment: why do you repeat the OP's not at all readable example code?

Comment: Because it is the concrete solution to a concrete question.

Comment: If it was me providing such code to my team members, I would be kindly ask for changing this unreadable (one-liner) code immediately.

Comment: That is not the question

Comment: Thus your attitude/approach is to always immediately deliver what was  ask for and not inform a possible customer or team member about possible pitfalls or code smells?

Comment: That happens too often at SO. You ask a concrete question and want a concrete answer. I think this place is not for a discussion about liking ternery operators.

Comment: Problem is there is a lot better way to answer it without having code repeated over and over. The code is very inefficient.

Comment: There was no question about efficience, extracting methods or other refactorings.

Comment: Lets discuss via PN?

Comment: I added some prosa to the answer. Hope you like it.